# AngularJS passing constants in an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes

Alright, I am trying to pass an AngularJS constant value towards a Directive. I am doing this in order to be able to have a few constant values that I can change later in development.

The constants are defined as followed:

```
TLKApp.constant("NOBILITY", 
{
    "Soldier": 0,
    "Knight": 1,
    "Duke": 2
});
TLKApp.constant("NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER", 0);
TLKApp.constant("NOBILITY_LEVEL_KNIGHT", 1);
TLKApp.constant("NOBILITY_LEVEL_DUKE", 2);
```

This is double because I wanted either case to work, but none do.

The directive:

```
TLKApp.directive("foldOutMenuDirective", [ '$rootScope', '$parse', function($rootScope, $parse) {
return {
    scope: { 
        title: '@',
        items: '=',
        nobility: '=?'
    },
    templateUrl: 'HTML/Directives/FoldOutMenu.html',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log("Nobility on attribute: "+$parse(attrs.nobility)(scope.$parent));
    }
};
}]);
```

The HTML:

```
<fold-out-menu-directive  title="Account" items="AccountMenuItems" nobility="NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER"></fold-out-menu-directive>
```

NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER will be printed as undefined. My question is, how do I pass this constant into the directive while it showing up as a the correct value? In addition, I would prefer to use NOBILITY.Soldier over NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER, but that seems to give even more trouble.

My only work around so far was this:

```
TLKApp.controller('NavigationMenuCtrl', ['$scope','NOBILITY','NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER', function($scope, NOBILITY, NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER) {
$scope.NobilitySoldier = NOBILITY_LEVEL_SOLDIER;
```

And in the HTML refer to NobilitySoldier, but this defeats the purpose of a single constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **$injector**.It lets you manually inject services or other components.try something like this.

```
return {
    scope: { 
        title: '@',
        items: '=',
        nobility: '=?'
    },
    templateUrl: 'HTML/Directives/FoldOutMenu.html',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        var nobil = $injector.get(attr.nobility); // nobil will be your constant        
    }
};
```

Comment: I would like to give a small thanks. I was getting really frustrated that I couldn't find the solution and this works perfectly. AngularJS is pretty big to get into.